# Modify CalendarView?

Tags: android, calendarview

I want to show a calendarview on my android application.
Default android calendar is not very nice.
I would like to improve the visual appearance and functionality of this calendar.
To do this, does anyone have a recommendation?

Answer (score 5):

If you find extending CalendarView to be as much of a headache as I did, you can always create your own CustomCalendarView. 
In your own View you can steal whatever functionality you like from the native CalendarView:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.1_r2/com/android/calendar/CalendarView.java

Answer (score -2):

https://code.google.com/p/ancal/source/checkout
That project obtains ability of creating appointments, tasks and notes on calendar.