# Android - Extending CalendarView

Tags: android, calendarview

I want to have a CalendarView that, on the top right corner of each day, shows a small number, which would mean the number of events for that concrete day.

I was doing some research on the topic and, apart from all the solutions previous to the existence of the CalendarView widget, I found little information on how to do that. 
In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214828/modify-calendarview), for example, it's said that extending CalendarView is quite difficult, so I'm asking you, guys, if anyone has faced a similar problem and can give me some general recommendations, advises, etc.

More concrete information like methods that are meant to be overwritten or code, are also super welcome!

Edit: Maybe it's worth saying that it is the first time that I'm going to extend an Android widget/view.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not a way of extending the CalendarView, I decided to post here a couple of alternatives that do allow the feature that I was needing, in case it helps someone.

- [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)
- [CalendarViewExtended](https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView)
- [TimeSquare](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) (this one I think it works exactly like the CalendarView widget)